# Unpermitted parameters when uploading image with tinymce

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [tinymce-rails-image-upload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload) to upload images with paperclip (following [this](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload-demo) demo-app). When I try to upload an image I'm getting an 'umpermitted parameters' reminder and the image doesn't upload. The upload modal shows 'Got a bad response from server':

```
Processing by TinymceAssetsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"auth token", "hint"=>"", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001025a2780   @tempfile=#  <File:/var/folders/t4/86vsrmds42j84r36kwpng7k00000gn/T/RackMultipart20150207- 12522-9rj6xq>, @original_filename="applecash.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";  filename=\"applecash.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "alt"=>""}
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/t4/86vsrmds42j84r36kwpng7k00000gn/T/RackMultipart20150207-12522-9rj6xq[0]' 2>/dev/null
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE (questions.position IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = 1) ORDER BY questions.position DESC  LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `file_content_type`
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("created_at", "file_content_type", "file_file_name", "file_file_size", "file_updated_at", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00], ["file_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["file_file_name", "timcook.jpg"], ["file_file_size", 120040], ["file_updated_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00], ["position", 9], ["updated_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00]]
(7.3ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```

Here's the controller:

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

def create
  geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file params[:file]
  question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)

  render json: {
    question: {
      url:    question.file.url,
      height: geometry.height.to_i,
      width:  geometry.width.to_i
    }
   }, layout: false, content_type: "text/html"

 end
end
```

and the question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comment, Question.new] do |f| %>    
  <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 60 %>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce plugins: ["uploadimage"] %>
```

Comment: It's ok to not permit some of the parameters, so `Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token` is a reminder, not an exception. I suggest you log what are `question` model instance errors:

   
    `logger.debug question.errors.full_messages (after  question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint) line)`

Comment: Ah, thank you, that shows the problem. I was validating the presence of the questions body and it was blank. However, now no error is showing but the image is still not uploading (edited question with new output).

Comment: I would add `:html => {:multipart => true}` option to the form:

    <%= simple_form_for [@comment, Question.new], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

I think the problem lies here:

    Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `file_content_type`

And maybe my suggestion would solve that.

Comment: Hmm, no luck. I'm a bit confused with the whole thing and I think I'll ask a new, more general question. If you'd like to post your original comment as an answer, I'll accept it, since it did solve my original problem. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to not permit some of the parameters, so Unpermitted parameters: `utf8, authenticity_token` is a reminder, not an exception. I suggest you log what are question model instance errors:

```
question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)
logger.debug question.errors.full_messages
```

Answer (score 0):

May be wrong, but, you have the following:

```
 question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)
```

I think you'd just make that read like this and it would work:

```
 question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint, :utf8, :authenticity_token)
```

The error is clear.   You have not permitted those parameters.   But they exist.   You expressly permit the other three there so I presume you have to permit those two additional.

That's my guess and I'm sticking to it :).

Comment: Hmm, valid guess but that gives me an 'unknown attribute: utf8' and 'unknown attribute: authenticity_token' error.

Comment: Well, that means the utf8 and authenticity_token columns do not exist in the database, which, I suspect, we knew because this is a tutorial and they didn't have it there.   Now, I assume if you add fields that can hold those parameters this will work, but that seems like an out of date tutorial OR I am way the hell off :).  I tried.

Comment: Well it's this new create action in the tinymce controller thats messing it up since questions were previously created with no errors. Ok well I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks for the help anyways :)